# How to dynamically access nested errors/touched on formik Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap, formik

I am trying to create a React component to abstract away creating an Input group for my form. All inputs have the same layout - a Label, with the Input underneath and if errors/info text is present these are displayed under the Input.

Previously I was handling my own form state/handlers. Now I am experimenting with formik (with Yup validation) and have run into a problem dynamically accessing the `error` and `touched` fields when I have nested information.

Here is my input group component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Label, Input, FormFeedback, FormText } from 'reactstrap';
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';

const InputGroup = ({ name, label, type, info, required }) => {
  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <Label htmlFor={name}>{label}{required && '*'}</Label>
      <Field name={name}>
        {({field, form}) => (
          <Input {...field} id={name} type={
                 invalid={form.errors[name] && form.touched[name]} //problem here
          />
        )}
      </Field>
      {info && <FormText color="muted">{info}</FormText>}
      <ErrorMessage name={name}>
          {msg => <FormFeedback>{msg}</FormFeedback>}
      </ErrorMessage>
    </FormGroup>
  )
}

InputGroup.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  info: PropTypes.string,
  required: PropTypes.bool
};

InputGroup.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  required: false
};
```

As I am using bootstrap (reactstrap@7.x), the `<FormFeedback>` element requires the accompanying `<Input>` to be labelled with an `invalid` tag.  In the above I dynamically assign `invalid=true/false` if the corresponding field on formik's `form.errors` object exists (ie. an error exists) and `form.touched` object is true (ie. the user has touched the input).

This works fine when formik is setup with a flat initialValues (eg. below), as the `invalid={form.errors[name] && form.touched[name]}` evaluates to (for eg.) `invalid={form.errors[firstName] && form.touched[firstName]}`

```
initialValues = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  password: ''
}
```

However, when formik is setup with a nested initialValues (eg. below),
the `invalid={form.errors[name] && form.touched[name]}` evaluates to `invalid={form.errors[name.first] && form.touched[name.first]}`. Ultimately, this will always evaluate to false, hence the input is always `invalid=false`, thusthe input is never marked with the error styling nor the error message displayed.

```
initialValues = {
  name: {
    first: '',
    last: ''
  },
  email: '',
  password: ''
}
```

How can I go about setting up my InputGroup component so that I can dynamically access the required fields on formik's error and touched objects regardless of whether it is flat or nested?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Formik has a function `getIn()` that can extract a value from an object by a path (e.g. a path being something like `name.first`).

```
<Field name={name}>
  {({ field, form }) => (
    <Input
      {...field}
      id={name}
      invalid={getIn(form.errors, name) && getIn(form.touched, name)}
    />
  )}
</Field>
```

See an [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7x6py9409) on CodeSandbox.

Comment: Excellent. I remembered Jared Palmer's React Alicante video on youtube and that formik supports lodash .get() with dot-syntax. Used lodash initially, but much better to have a built in method - one less package to work with.

Comment: dont forget to wrap the field name around backticks (``) like this- {getIn(form.errors, ` name `) && getIn(form.touched, ` name `)}

Answer (score 1):

Formik also supports `meta` argument from the `Field` component, there is information specified for the exact field (`value`, `touched`, `error`).

```
const CustomFormikInput = (props) => {   
    return <Field name={props.name}>
       {({ field, meta }) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(meta)); // Log meta output
            const errorMsg = meta.touched ? meta.error : undefined;
            return <div>
                     <input {...field} {...props} />
                     {errorMsg}
                   </div>;
        }}
    </Field>;
}
```

Comment: but `meta.touched` does not work correctly with nested field, i.e it always return false when you click submit without touching the field (which is contrary to what state in the doc: https://formik.org/docs/guides/form-submission#pre-submit)