# With Formik and Yup, how do I display a form error for a field of a nested object?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, nested-object, ionic7

I'm using React 18, Ionic 7, Formik 2.4 and Yup 0.32.  I have an object with a nested object

```
export type Person = {
  name: string
  address: Address
}
```

The address objecdt is defined as

```
export type Address = {
  city: string
}

export default Address
```

My Yup schemas are defined similarly

```
export const personValidationSchema = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string().required('First Name is required'),
  address: addressValidationSchema
})
```

The address schema is defined as

```
export const addressValidationSchema = Yup.object({
  city: Yup.string().required('City is required')
})
```

I'm not sure how to set up my error display logic to display an error if someone doesn't fill in a city in their Formik form.  I have this

```
        <IonInput
            aria-label='City'
            placeholder='City'
            value={formikProps.values.address.city}
            onIonChange={(e) => formikProps.setFieldValue('address.city', e.detail.value)}
            name='address.city'
          />
          {formikProps.touched.address.city && formikProps.errors.address.city ? (
            <IonNote slot='error'>{formikProps.errors.address.city}</IonNote>
          ) : null}
```

The error if no name is entered displays just fine ...

```
          <IonInput
            aria-label='Name'
            placeholder='Name'
            value={formikProps.values.name}
            onIonChange={(e) => formikProps.setFieldValue('name', e.detail.value)}
            name='name'
          />
          {formikProps.touched.name && formikProps.errors.name ? (
            <IonNote slot='error'>{formikProps.errors.name}</IonNote>
          ) : null}
```

What else do I need to do?  The example of this not working can be found here --
https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-v3s4ke?file=src%2Fschemas%2Faddress-schema.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx,src%2Fschemas%2Fperson-schema.ts,src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically access nested errors/touched on formik Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089054/how-to-dynamically-access-nested-errors-touched-on-formik-field)

Comment: I tried "getIn" but that doesnt' seem to work either -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-f9x6rb?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Ftypes%2Fperson.type.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-v3s4ke?file=src%2Fschemas%2Faddress-schema.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx,src%2Fschemas%2Fperson-schema.ts,src%2FApp.tsx) you posted and the bug I found was in `MyForm` component. `initialFormValues` had a typo in the spelling of `city`

```
 const initialFormValues: Person = {
    name: '',
    address: {
     ity: '', // this is the typo
    },
  };
```

this would be the correct fix

```
 const initialFormValues: Person = {
    name: '',
    address: {
     city: '', // this is the fix
    },
  };
```

Here's the complete component fix

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonCheckbox,
  IonIcon,
  IonPage,
  IonContent,
  IonNote,
  IonButton,
  IonInput,
} from '@ionic/react';
import { pencilOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import Person from './types/person.type';
import { personValidationSchema } from '../schemas/person-schema';
import { Formik, FormikProps } from 'formik';

const MyForm: React.FC = () => {
  const formikRef = useRef<FormikProps<Person>>(null);
  const initialFormValues: Person = {
    name: '',
    address: {
      city: '',
    },
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      innerRef={formikRef}
      initialValues={initialFormValues}
      validationSchema={personValidationSchema}
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        alert('Saved!');
      }}
    >
      {(formikProps) => (
        <form onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}>
          <IonInput
            aria-label="Name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={formikProps.values.name}
            onIonChange={(e) =>
              formikProps.setFieldValue('name', e.detail.value)
            }
            name="name"
          />
          {formikProps.touched.name && formikProps.errors.name ? (
            <IonNote slot="error">{formikProps.errors.name}</IonNote>
          ) : null}

          <IonInput
            aria-label="City"
            placeholder="City"
            value={formikProps.values.address.city}
            onIonChange={(e) =>
              formikProps.setFieldValue('address.city', e.detail.value)
            }
            name="address.city"
          />
          {formikProps.touched.address?.city &&
          formikProps.errors.address?.city ? (
            <IonNote slot="error">{formikProps.errors.address.city}</IonNote>
          ) : null}

          <IonButton type="submit">Save</IonButton>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that to display errors using formik and yup, you are using  `formikProps.errors` and its structure match the structure of the form values.

One more thing, your error path for city looks wrong.it should be `address.city`

Try using the below component -

```
<IonInput
  aria-label='City'
  placeholder='City'
  value={formikProps.values.address.city}
  onIonChange={(e) => formikProps.setFieldValue('address.city', e.detail.value)}
  name='address.city'
/>
{formikProps.touched.address?.city && formikProps.errors.address?.city ? (
  <IonNote slot='error'>{formikProps.errors.address.city}</IonNote>
) : null}
```

The above change in the code that I have includes is that - i am using `formikProps.touched.address?.city` instead of `formikProps.touched.address.city`. Also the same goes with `formikProps.errors.address?.city` instead of `formikProps.errors.address.city`.

Plus, set your initial values  -

```
const initialValues: Person = {
  name: '',
  address: {
    city: '',
  },
};
```

With the above changes, you should be able to display errors for the city field within the nested address object.

Let me know if that works.